# Dialog chaining in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In jquery i'm often use modal dialog chaining technique. F.e.

```
$.Deferred().resolve().promise()
    .then(function ()
    {
        return runDialog1(someProps); // return promise
    })
    .then(function (runDialog1Result)
    {
        ... some processing
        return runDialog2(muchMoreProps); // return promise
    })
    .then(function (runDialog2Result)
    {
        ... some more processing
        postDataToServer(someDialog1AndDialog2Props);
    })

);
```

In react i had to use state to show/hide modal dialog and props methods

```
<CustomDialog
    open={this.state.isCusomDialogOpen}
    onOk={this.onCustomDialogOk}
    onCancel={this.onCustomDialogCancel}
...
```

Is there a way to make modal dialogs "chainable" in react?

Comment: Just open next dialog onCustomDialogOk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind adding a library for this, [`react-modal-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal-promise) offers a really nice API that's pretty much exactly what you described. You can use it like this:

```
const App = {
    // ...
    return (
        // ...
        <ModalContainer />
        // ...
    )
}

const MyModal = ({ isOpen, onResolve, message }) => (
  <Modal open={isOpen} onHide={() => onResolve(false)}>
      {message}
      <button onClick={() => onResolve(true)}>Confirm</button>
  </Modal>
)

const myPromiseModal = createModal(MyModal)

// bare promises 
myPromiseModal({ message: 'Confirm value 1?' })
    .then(value1 => {
        doStuff(value1)

        return myPromiseModal({ message: 'Confirm value 2?' })
    }).then(value2 => {
        doStuff(value2)
    })

// async/await 
const value1 = await myPromiseModal({ message: 'Confirm value 1?' })
doStuff(value1)

const value2 = await myPromiseModal({ message: 'Confirm value 2?' })
doStuff(value2)
```

Comment: Exactly what i need! 
Can you please suggest how to return typed object by onResolve method in TypeScript instead on "any"?

Comment: [CodeSandbox demo with typed resolve value](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-modal-promise-binary-mask-tl1tu?file=/src/Modal.tsx). There might be a nicer way to do it with generics — react-modal-promise is written in TS, so you can check out the source code if you want to figure out a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at: https://github.com/eBay/nice-modal-react . It provides promise api to manage modals.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a switch for every step in CustomDialog componet. a pattern could be:

```
<CustomDialog open={!!this.state.isCusomDialogOpen}>
<>
{
this.state.isCusomDialogOpen === 1 && (
<div>step 1</div>
)
}
{
this.state.isCusomDialogOpen === 2 && (
<div>step 2</div>
)
}
</>
</CustomDialog>
```